# How to intall whatsapp plus

Tags: motorola-droid-razr

I downloaded whatsapp plus and I installed it on my phone...when am doing the initialization... where they ask you to put ur number there...I put my number there and when the thing was loading...they told me to install the new version on Google play store...uninstall original whatsapp and download whatsapp plus..I uninstalled the whatsapp and downloaded the whatsapp plus but still...they said that thing again...I tried doing they "call me thing" and they told me" it seems ur client has been modified...please download the new version from Google play store..my friend uses the same phone(Motorola droid RAZR) and the whatsapp plus is working perfectly for him...pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

These happens sometimes. But after 1 or 2 try it will work. 
Try these steps.

***Make Sure you have perfectly running whatsapp installed with your important chat***

1) Go to /sdcard/whatsapp/databases/
Delete all files using FILE MANAGER.
In Whatsapp Go to Settings>Chat settings>Backup Conversations to Backup your conversations ...

2) Uninstall OLDER WHATSAPP

3) Install Given WhatsApp+'s apk ...

4) Open it & Click AGREE & CONTINUE & enter your number

5) If you have done above steps well then there should be RESTORE BUTTON , Press it
(If you Dont get restore button or you get message like "Your app is not official Download from play store" 
then
uninstall current whatsapp+ & install original whatsapp from play store , do verification process and then chat with 1-2 person again backup chats and then uninstall original whatsapp & install given WhatsApp+ You will get RESTORE button)

6) Wait ...it might take some long... Press Continue after it finishes